# React Redux how to properly distribute components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**I have a store in Redux, I'm making an online clothes shop with products for Womans and Mens**

```
const defaultState = {
  womanProducts: 
   [
     {
       name: "Mini Skirt", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/I/0/1/p/8399/316/800/8399316800_4_1_8.jpg?t=1656932863233&imwidth=563", 
       price: 35, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 1.1,
     }, 
     {
       name: "Basic Jeans", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/I/0/1/p/8685/326/400/8685326400_4_1_8.jpg?t=1657798996961&imwidth=563", 
       price: 39, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 1.2,
     }, 
     {  
       name: "Fit Dress", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/V/0/1/p/4390/422/611/4390422611_4_1_8.jpg?t=1643722977148&imwidth=563", 
       price: 45, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 1.3,
     }, 
     {
       name: "Basic Sweatshirt", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2021/I/0/1/p/8393/363/485/8393363485_4_1_8.jpg?t=1634212398331&imwidth=563", 
       price: 29, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 1.4,
     }
   ],
  manProducts: 
   [
     {
       name: "Basic Hoodie", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/I/0/2/p/8591/513/250/05/8591513250_6_1_8.jpg?t=1648556110506&imwidth=563", 
       price: 39, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 2.1,
     }, 
     {
       name: "Basic Jeans", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/I/0/2/p/8591/513/827/03/8591513827_6_1_8.jpg?t=1646659329763&imwidth=563", 
       price: 29, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 2.2,
     }, 
     {
       name: "Black Shorts", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2021/I/0/2/p/4695/507/800/4695507800_4_1_8.jpg?t=1629285223879&imwidth=563", 
       price: 19, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 2.3,
     }, 
     {
       name: "Naruto Set", 
       img: "https://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos//2022/V/0/2/p/4693/700/800/4693700800_4_1_8.jpg?t=1643120792610&imwidth=563", 
       price: 59, 
       inCart: 1, 
       id: 2.4,
     }
   ],
   cartProducts: [],

 }
```

**And also I have a two components, where I get products from store, drawing them in two pages and there is function to add products to shopping cart**

**Components:**

WomanProducts:

```
export default function WomansProducts() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selector = useSelector(state => state);
  const womanProducts = selector.womanProducts;
  const cartProducts = selector.cartProducts;

  const addProducts = (id) => {
      let isInCart = false;
      cartProducts.forEach(el => {
          if(id === el.id) {
              isInCart = true
          }
      })
      if(!isInCart) {
          dispatch({type: "ADD_PRODUCTS", payload: womanProducts.find((product) => id === product.id)})
      }
  }

  return (
      <div className="mainProducts">
          {womanProducts.map(item => 
              <div className="womanProduct" key={item.id}>
                  <img src={item.img} />
                  <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                  <h3>{item.price}$</h3>
                  <button onClick={() => addProducts(item.id)}>Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
          )}
      </div>
  )
```

}

MenProducts:

```
export default function MansProducts() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selector = useSelector(state => state);
  const manProducts = selector.manProducts;
  const cartProducts = selector.cartProducts;

  const addProducts = (id) => {
      let isInCart = false;
      cartProducts.forEach(el => {
          if(id === el.id) {
            isInCart = true
          }
      })
      if(!isInCart) {
          dispatch({type: "ADD_PRODUCTS", payload: manProducts.find((product) => id === product.id)})
      }
  } 

  return (
      <div className="mainProducts">
          {manProducts.map(item => 
              <div className="manProduct" key={item.id}>
                  <img src={item.img} />
                  <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                  <h3>{item.price}$</h3>
                  <button onClick={() => addProducts(item.id)}>Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
          )}
      </div>
  )
```

}

**These components are the same, is it okay or I should to distribute this components? And how?**

Comment: have a single component named `product` ... pass down the props with a difference to make such as a `gender` and its related property values and show that accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If both components are the same only difference is the state then you can make it to a common component and only need to pass the different states all manage by common component.